# Plugin access and control panel navigation

Tags: plugin-development, admin

I have created a plugin.  It works fine for admins.  The plugin is in the CP nav and the admins urls work as expected, but when I login as a user who is not admin, the plugin will not display in the CP nav and the user cannot view the urls.  You get the error message:

```
 You don’t have the proper credentials to access this page.
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must give your users the “Access [Plugin Name]” permission.

You can either grant that permission directly to each individual user from Users → [User Name] → Permissions, or if each of the users belongs to the same user group, you can go to Settings → Users → [User Group Name] and grant the permission from there instead.